# javascript / jquery: detecting which of two elements is in front

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, positioning

I have a bunch of elements, positioned via a variety of methods (absolute, fixed, and static), with various z-indexes, where some are parents of others.  Is there a simple, general way of determining, for any two elements, which one is in front of the other?

The approach I'm thinking of is this:

```
Let A and B be the two elements.  
Let X and Y be two sibling elements such that X is A or an ancestor of A, and Y is B or an ancestor of B.  
If X has a higher z-index than Y, then A is in front of B.
```

However, that seems like a lot of code for a simple problem, and I'm also worried there might be corner cases where it doesn't give the right answer.  Anyone have a better idea?

Comment: I mean, the computed style for those elements will return whatever the parent element's z-index is, if it's set. `static` elements don't receive a z-index, they use `auto` which will then default up the tree. If they have no parent with a position other than static and a z-index, then they'll only ever have auto, which is also not 0 for all intents and purposes.

Comment: If you have an id of an x,y point at which they all might overlap, you can use `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)` to return the front-most element.

Comment: @Shmiddty: I thought about that but the intersection point might have a 3rd element on top of it (the use-case is drag-n-drop code, so the thing I'm dragging might obscure the intersection)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: So, I only care about this when the elements actually intersect, and two static elements can't intersect AFAIK.  So if I default to treating "auto" as below a numeric z-index, it should work, since absolutely positioned elements are always above static siblings, right?

Comment: Perhaps you should expand your question. If you're looking for the element in which a dragged object is dropped, you should be able to listen to the "dropped" event (I forget the specific name of the event). The event target will be that element.

Comment: Eh unfortunately it's complicated.  I'm dragging multiple elements, and defining the drop target based on the thing that contains all of them, so I don't think I can rely on mouse events... looking at coordinates and figuring out what's in front seems to be my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with.  Not great.  Makes a few assumptions that generally work for me, but might not work for you:

- Assumes that children are always in front of their parents (you can break this assumption by mixing relative and absolute positioning)
- Assumes that you don't give two siblings the same z-index.  Counts auto as 0.

Here's the code (in coffeescript, using jquery):

```
is_in_front_of = (div1, div2) ->

    z_index = (d) ->
        z = d.css 'z-index'
        z ?= 0
        if z == 'auto' then z = 0
        return z

    if $.contains div1[0], div2[0]
        return false

    if $.contains div2[0], div1[0]
        return true            

    while div1.parent().length > 0 and not $.contains div1.parent()[0], div2[0]
        div1 = div1.parent()

    while div2.parent().length > 0 and not $.contains div2.parent()[0], div1[0]
        div2 = div2.parent()

    return z_index(div1) > z_index(div2)
```